# WKWebViewでリンクがタップされたことを、指が離れる前に検知したい

Tags: ios, webview, swift2

WKWebViewを使用したアプリを開発しているのですが、ユーザーがリンクをタップされたことを、指が離れる前に検知したいと考えています。

リンクがタップされると、didStartProvisionalNavigation や　didFinishNavigation　といったWKNavigationDelegateのメソッドが呼ばれますが、これらが発火するのはユーザーが指を離してからです。

指が離れる前に検知する良い方法をご存知の方がいましたら、ご教示ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: WKWebViewでリンクがタップされた際に、指が離れる前に検知することは難しいと思います。因みに、どういったことをするために必要と考えられていますか？そこから、別の方法が導き出せる方がいるかもしれないので、追記頂くと回答の可能性が広がるかもしれません。

Comment: レスありがとうございます。タブブラウザーを開発しており、リンクを長押しすると新しいタブを開く挙動を実装したいのです。

現状ではWKNavigationDelegateを起点にタブを開いており、これはうまく動いているのですが、長押ししている間全く何のフィードバックもユーザーに返らないので、ユーザーテストをするとそこに違和感を感じるユーザーがとても多く、何とか解決したいと考えてます。

Sleipnirなどのタブブラウザを触ってみると同様の機能をWebviewのタッチアップではなく、タッチダウン時点で検知しているのがわかるので何か方法があるのではないかと考えた次第です。

今の所、http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358774/how-can-i-reliably-detect-a-link-click-in-uiwebview　などを参考にして、Javascriptをインジェクトすることでハックできないかトライしてみようと思っています。

他に何か良い方法があれば、ぜひアドバイスお願い致します。

Comment: 追加情報ありがとうございます。少し調べてみましたが、やはり標準ではWKWebViewでは長押しを検知できない気がします。リンク長押しで新しいタブを開くためには、最低限、URLを取得する必要はありそうですね…。私の方で「url リンク 長押し ios」と検索して、幾つか関連しそうなサイトを見つけましたので、参考までに貼っておきますね。これまでの事例を見ても力技の方が多そうです…。「http://qiita.com/meta2/items/798eca8f565c3dde6b1e」、「http://takemasa5.tumblr.com/post/4549914421/uiwebview%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E9%95%B7%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%97%E6%99%82%E3%81%AEactionsheet」、「http://harrymaya.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/06/20/205159」あたりが参考になると思います。